# Join two graphQl queries into one

Tags: java, graphql

I have two queries which return list of the same type.
I need to make third query which should use lists from other two queries, join them and then return different list. I ran into problem with passing lists into third query. How can i get data from one query and pass it into other's input.

```
type Query{
getList1:[User]
getList2:[User]
mergeLists:[User]
}
type User {
  id: ID
  name: String
}
```

mergeLists Query gets data from getList1 and getList2, on the server present method witch gets two lists and merges it which i will call in resolver. I don't know how to transfer data to mergeLists.

Comment: this question needs more detail - please give us all of the code that you can and also a stack trace and any other information about the error

Comment: that's better??

Comment: i found some info about @export directive, but GraphQL for java does not have support of it. Maybe there is some other ways to do that

Comment: maybe there is the way how to send two queries at once using third.

Comment: maybe NOT ... @export directive can be supported on BE and FE ... and is **usually** used for nested types, not usable in parallel ... without specific support ... just query both source arrays (in one query), connect data (on FE/client) and use it in 2nd query, no other way, no magic

Comment: can you show an example please?

Comment: nothing to show, use normal queries ... for normal queries follow normal tutorials for your env