# GraphQL interpolation between queries

Tags: graphql

I have graphQL query that essentially queries two datasources. I need to pass some data returned from the first part of the query to the second part. i.e. Pass the returned `hostname` from the `config` query to the `CommonName` in the `GetCertificate` query. e.g.

```
query get_config {
  config {
    id
    hostname
  }
  getCertificate(
      CommonName: "siggi") {
    Certificate
    Key
  }
  }
```

Pretty sure this can be done but all of the examples seem to provide for static variables only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66335618/6124657

Comment: Hmm that post doesn't make sense to me. It doesn't seem to explain anything.

Comment: if not supported in API then simply not possible, make 2 requests

Comment: So are we saying this is not supported in GraphQL ?

Comment: can be but usually not

Comment: what lang/env/server? are you responsible for BE? ... if you make a `certificate` a child prop of `config` then `config.certificate` resolver can simply access `parent.id` (using 1st resolver arg, usually named 'parent')

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You would need to make certificate a child of config and use schema delegation to pass parent resolver return values to child resolvers.

```
query get_config {
  config {
    id
    hostname
    certificate {
      Certificate
      Key
    }
  }
}
```

Your schema would have a query for the certificate that accepts the hostname:

```
  getCertificate(hostname: String) {
    Certificate
    Key
  }
```

Resolvers use delegateToSchema function.

```
resolvers: {
    config: {
        fragment: `fragment ConfigFragment on config { hostname }`,
        resolve(config, args, context, info) {
            return info.mergeInfo?.delegateToSchema({
                schema: theSchema,
                operation: "query",
                fieldName: "getCertificate",
                args: {
                    hostname: config.hostname,
                },
                context,
                info,
            });
        },
    },
},
```

See this doc on [schema delegation](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-delegation/) for detailed examples.

Comment: assuming it's about js env and access to BE code

Comment: Now we're talking let me try this.

Comment: Thanks @glen Thomas.  OK so I'm using the GraphiQL explorer that come with Hasura. However, I'm not sure where you would add the schema and define the resolver.